# ERROR 1064 mysql error

Tags: mysql, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE references ( hamsterId MEDIUMINT(9), id MEDIUMINT(9), complete BINARY(1));
```

i keep running error messages ive tried many possiblities and have not answers help would be appriciated thank you!Also is BINARY(1) correct for allowing only a 1 or 0 allowance.
By the way this is the error message :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the  manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references ( hamsterId MEDIUMINT(9), id MEDIUMINT(9), complete BINARY(1))' at line 1

Comment: `references` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). To use it as a table or column identifier, you must enclose it in backticks as `CREATE TABLE \`references\`...`

Answer (score 1):

use backtics for reserved  name   `REFERENCES`  is a reversed word for mysql see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

```
 CREATE TABLE `references` ( hamsterId MEDIUMINT(9), id MEDIUMINT(9), complete BINARY(1));
```

Comment: what is the "reverded name"

Comment: @KaiHayati   is a type   reserved name and not reverded  .. anyway i have update the answer